# Can we connect XCode Simulator in a running Flutter container?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter, docker

For my project, I am developing a flutter app for ios and android devices and I am creating a dev environment with docker so all the members can use the same environment to build the mobile application.

I have created a flutter docker container using the following document

https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-dockerize-flutter-apps/

The document covers the section where we have to connect an Andriod device in order to use it as a simulator. In my use case, we want to use the simulator to test and debug our application. Since the application will be built inside the container, is there a way we can connect a locally installed simulator to the docker container?

For example, If I start an Xcode simulator on my mac and run the flutter build from the docker container, I want to have that built run on the simulator which is running on my mac